# iOS Could not get new touchEvent when touch two view with same parent view under a Same ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

[image]
Here I have view like this pic
A,B was addSubView to C, C add SubView to D ViewController's View, I override D ViewController's touchxx functions (like touchesBegan..),And first I touch Area A and keep that touchEvent,Then start another touch in Area B, But the weird thing is I can't get any new events when I touch B Area(and C Area)
I'm guessing when iOS dispatching the touchEvents it may first compare two View's parent View(here A,B and C) Then under this View the new touchEvent would be ignored?

So the question is whether I was wrong about the question,Or Is there any trick or some way to hack made this TouchEvent appear?

**Update: I found I set A & B UIImageView in my initial implementation, so this issue appears, If A & B are UIView then do not have this issue ...**

Comment: I didn't get the question properly :-(. U are  touching in "A" view and without removing ur finger touching in "B" view with another finger and B views touch event is not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

What you currently do is capture touches of D, not A. If you don't capture touch event of A then it will passthrough to it's subview C, and because C don't capture touch event it will passthrough to D. When you touch B, without B capturing touch event, you are actually touching again D.

To capture multiple touches of D you need multitouch gesture recogniser or enable multitouch of the D view.

Answer (score 0):

If any other faced the similar issues, Then u may use some Control not UIView (here UIImageView), Then just replace it with UIView . If needs the background image of the UIImageView like me then just add a extension to the UIView

```
 extension UIView{

    func setBackgroundImage(img: UIImage){

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
        img.draw(in: self.bounds)
        if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
        }else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
    }
}
```

**PS: I Still cant configure it out why iOS do that thing 4 me  :(**